# Animação "speed up" - js

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html5

olá gostaria de saber como faço em js ou se tem algum plugin que facilite daquelas animações de paginas unicas. Você clica no menu e ele desce até a seção que você selecionou, consigo fazer animação com uma velocidade fixa, mas queria fazer com que ela comece um pouco devagar e aumente com o decorrer do scroll...

***tenho um exemplo aqui*** >> http://www.sergioarantes.com/

SE ALGUEM PUDER PFF AJUDE !!

desde já agradeço

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O conceito desse efeito pode ser baseado no [easing jquery](https://jqueryui.com/easing/), porém esse site utilizou [esse plugin](http://www.thepetedesign.com/demos/onepage_scroll_demo.html).
Além desses outros:

http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/
http://fitvidsjs.com/
http://suprb.com/apps/gridalicious/
https://mixitup.kunkalabs.com/

Espero ter ajudado.